# PDF file encode to base64 take more time if 100k documents are to be encode

Tags: java, base64, fileinputstream

Am trying to encode pdf documents to base64, If it is less in number ( like 2000 documents) its working nicely. But am having `100k` plus doucments to be encode.

Its take more time to encode all those files. Is there any better approach to encode large data set.?

Please find my current approach

```
 String filepath=doc.getPath().concat(doc.getFilename());

 file = new File(filepath);
    if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            encodedfile = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
            fileInputStreamReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you seen this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082816/java-buffered-base64-encoder-for-streams

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Figure out how many files you need to encode.

   ```
   int files = Files.list(Paths.get(directory)).count();
   ```
2. Split them up into a reasonable amount that a thread can handle in java. I.E) If you have 100k files to encode. Split it into 1000 lists of 1000, something like that.

   ```
   int currentIndex = 0;
   for (File file : filesInDir) {
       if (fileMap.get(currentIndex).size() >= cap)
           currentIndex++;
       fileMap.get(currentIndex).add(file);
   }
   /** Its going to take a little more effort than this, but its the idea im trying to show you*/
   ```
3. Execute each worker thread one after another if the computers resources are available.

   ```
   for (Integer key : fileMap.keySet()) {
        new WorkerThread(fileMap.get(key)).start();
   }
   ```

You can check the current resources available with:

```
 public boolean areResourcesAvailable() {
     return imNotThatNice();
 }

/**
 * Gets the resource utility instance
 * 
 * @return the current instance of the resource utility
 */
private static OperatingSystemMXBean getInstance() {
    if (ResourceUtil.instance == null) {
        ResourceUtil.instance = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    }
    return ResourceUtil.instance;
}
```